# Urban Center Boundary

Tags: arcgis-desktop, density, population, boundaries

I want to create an urban center boundary (in ArcGIS v10.3) by using a population-grid dataset.

So, I selected high density cells, that is to say cells with population over 1.500 and hereupon I want to check each of the high density cell if it touches another high density cell, provided that diagonal touching is not allowed.

Any ideas or tools for doing this task quickly?

Comment: Reclassify and use region group with relevant neighborhood option

Comment: I see that my tip solved you issue http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214411/polygon-gap-filling. -1 from me for not acknowledging this

Comment: Sorry FelixIP, but i am new here and i am not familiar with the "rules"...Bytheway how i can acknowledge your contribution? I cant see any like button or something similar...

Comment: Write in the comments. Also make some minor change to the question so that I can remove my down vote