# Polygon gap filling

Tags: arcgis-desktop, donut-polygons, boundaries

I am working in ArcGIS and I have an urban center boundary, generated by a population-grid dataset. However, I want to fill in the gaps inside the urban center boundary (see the image below areas marked with red).

Any ideas to do this task?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Create a copy of your features, apply following field calculator expression on field Shape, using Python parser:

```
def outRing(shp):
 part=shp.getPart(0)
 pgon=arcpy.Polygon(part)
 return pgon
```

## ------------------------

```
outRing( !Shape!)
```

When working on shapefile, no need to switch editing on.

Comment: Seems there's a similar question here : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66049/removing-only-donut-holes-from-polygons-using-arcgis-desktop?rq=1 but it didn't find an answer like @FelixIP's. That seems a nice piece of coding :)

Comment: Although @FelixIP's code didn't work (i used the code version with !shape!), I solved the problem by using the feature to polygon tool.

Comment: @FelixIP, I think it will patch the right hand side one but not the other.

Comment: @AlexBartzokas, do you mind sharing how you did resolve this issue by using Feature to Polygon?

Comment: @fatih_dur agree, because left hand polygon is very special case of "donut" that is not the donut in my opinion. Feature to polygon, yeah right

Comment: Hi! By using the Feature to polygon, the outcome was the following:

Comment: http://image.prntscr.com/image/12efe6198fe54068b4a7b0ad3cdbc5b8.png